# using local storage to store and retrieve current clicked item on listview jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, local-storage, jquery, jquery-mobile-listview

I have a dynamic list view and what I am trying to do is store the list that is CURRENTLY  being clicked to local storage and retrieve it. I have the following code, it seems to work but I'm not sure so could someone give me a heads up if it's correct as I need to be doing more things with the data.

The html for list view:

```
<ul data-role="listview"  id="newsfeedposts" data-theme="a" data-overlay-theme="a" data-inline="true"data-inset="true"></ul>
```

the markup for each list item:

```
markup += '<li><a href="#fbfullpostviewpage" class="item" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-overlay-theme="e" data-inline="true"><img src="' + thumb_url + '">' +'<h4>' + name + '</h4><p>' +'posted this photo....</p><p>'+likes+'<img src="images/facebook-like-16.png"></p></a></li>';


$('#newsfeedposts').append(markup);
addPostToLocalStorage(posts);
$('#newsfeedposts').listview("refresh");
```

The method to add the item to storage and retrieve it;

```
function  addPostToLocalStorage(facebookPost){

$(".item").on('click', function (){
  var i = $('.item').index(this);
  console.log(i);

  localStorage['results'] = JSON.stringify(facebookPost[i]);
  storedItem = (localStorage['results']) ;
        console.log(storedItem);
         alert("this post was added to local storage");

        //retrieve  list item
         var retrievedItem = localStorage.getItem(['results']);


         console.log( 'retrieved: ' + retrievedItem);
       });
```

Comment: seems right to me..what problems do u face?

Comment: @hungerpain thanks, i figured it out, inorder to work with the data I had to parse the string back to a JSON object so did this: var facebookPost2 = JSON.parse(retrievedData); and it  worked. cheers